# TypeError: object is not a function with async.waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am a node.js noob trying to use [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback).
I have problems to get from the last task of the waterfall array to the final callback method.

In the example below I am passing the callback to `doSomethingAsync`, but when I want to execute the callback inside `doSomethingAsync` I get `TypeError: object is not a function`. I don't understand. Thank you for your thoughts

**EDIT**:

The first task of the waterfall is the creation of a Mongo document. The callback of the save() function is `function(err){...}`.

```
var session = createSession(); // session is a Mongoose model
async.waterfall([

    function (callback) {
        ...
        session.save(callback); // Model.save(function(err){...}
    },

    function (callback) {
        doSomethingAsync(session, callback)
    }

], function (err, session) {


});

function doSomethingAsync(session, callback){
    doSomething(function(err){
        callback(err,session);
    }
}


 callback(err,session);
 ^
 TypeError: object is not a function
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that the problem lies in code you have removed. More specifically, you probably had a function in the waterfall right before the one you've shown that calls `doSomethingAsync()`.

The way [`async.waterfall()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback) works is that it passes on any arguments passed to the callback to the next function in the function list. So the previous function is probably doing something like `callback(null, { foo: 'bar' })` and your `callback` argument in the next function is actually `{ foo: 'bar' }` and the second argument is the real callback. It really depends on how many arguments you passed previously to the callback.

So assuming you just pass 1 item, you would change the function definition from:

```
function (callback) {
    doSomethingAsync(session, callback)
}
```

to:

```
function (someResult, callback) {
    doSomethingAsync(session, callback)
}
```

Comment: I had indeed omitted the first task of the waterfall. Could you please have a look to the edit? I understand 'callback' is an object of another type, but I don't understand what is wrong in my syntax.

Comment: @NathanZ in the second function of the waterfall, the first argument needs to be the result that is passed to the first function's callback. In this case, it is the saved session. The second function needs to be `function(savedSession, callback){...`

Comment: From reading [the mongoose code](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/dd4f05dbeb9cd144071209f38a465e86377d9164/lib/model.js#L163), it looks like the function passed to `.save()` is actually given 3 arguments: error object (if any), saved model, and numberAffected. So I think your second function will need to have a signature of `function (savedSession, numAffected, callback) {`.